# Why doesn't mod run, but instead gives error "TEST1 TEST2 disabled"?

Tags: eclipse, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to run this on 1.7.10 Minecraft/ 1.7.10 Forge, in the Eclipse IDE.
The mod doesn't run, generates the error TEST1 TEST2 disabled.

This is the source code:

```
package com.matthew.newmod;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

@Mod(modid = tutorial.MODID, version = tutorial.VERSION)
public class tutorial
{
public static final String MODID = "new mod";
public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

@EventHandler
public void init(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
{

    GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Blocks.diamond_ore), new Object[] {
            "AAA",
            "AAA",
            "AAA",
            'A', Items.stick
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, your code is fine. It is something with the mod either not being enabled or you need to re-boot Minecraft with your new mod after you save your work in Eclipse.

I had the same issue and I thought it was something with the Test 1, Test 2, Disabled mods showing but that's there even with the mod working.

I ended up making a new mod with a new name. **After that, I just restarted Minecraft. Then, at the home menu, I chose mods, searched for my mod, and enabled it.**

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change your MOD_ID to something like "newmod" just to keep things neat but that space didn't cause me any issues.

I imported your code and tested just to be safe. The crafting of the sticky-diamond ore worked perfectly.

If you are in fact able to get into the game and it is showing the:

```
Test 1
TEST 2
DISABLED
```

In the "Mod Options" in the "Options" menu, don't stress. This is just because those are a default option. You can alter these placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason may be that you are initializing a crafting recipe on the PreInitializationEvent, and the game is attempting to create a crafting recipe for an item that has yet to load (or doesn't even exist). As an extra measure, no matter when my items are initialized (Pre or on initialize) I put my crafting on "PostInitializationEvent"